# How can I make a dynamic getter/setter

Tags: javascript

I already know how getters/setters work. for example, making inneHTML work on NodeLists

```
Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype,'innerHTML',{set:function(a,b){for(b in this)if(this[b])this[b]['innerHTML']=a}})
```

I would like to make an object that outputs something based on the property that is being accessed.

ex:

```
dynamicGetter = function(property){return querySelectorAll(property)}
myObject["div>ul>li>a"][0].innerHTML = "foo"
myObject.div[0].style.background="red"
```

How can I do that? Is it possible?

Comment: Wouldn't using a simple function would be better?

Comment: You can't, javascript don't have such thing.

Comment: In the future we'll be able to use proxy objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: Currently, there is no catch-all property getter/setter. [`__noSuchMethod__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/NoSuchMethod) is the closest you can get, currently. And it's not even standard.

Comment: @biziclop proxies look promissing! I can't wait for it to be implemented in most browsers, it only works on firefox atm...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it:
Currently, this only works in firefox :(

```
myObject = Proxy.create({
  get: function(x,property) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(property);
  }
});

myObject["div>ul>li>a"][0].innerHTML = "foo"
myObject.div[0].style.background="red"
```